# on_actionfoobar_triggered() open a new form.ui

Tags: c++, qt

I have form1.ui with a `qmenu` with `foobar` item, in `on_actionfoobar_triggered()` I want to open form2.ui, could anyone provide me an example for that?

Answer (score -1):

Solved this using a `QDialog`, no need to load another ui

```
void MainWindow::on_actionfoobar_triggered()
{
    Dialog MyDialog;
    MyDialog.setModal(true);
    MyDialog.exec();
}
```